# Require debugging assistance in cat function to get the proper column numbers

Tags: debugging, awk

I was hoping to get some debugging help. I am not very experienced in awk, or unix commands so I am simply throwing code together or using existing code to get what I want.

I'm recieving this error when running a custom script borrowed from another lab:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "extractConstitutiveAlternativeStrictAndTolerantExonIntron.py", line 41, in <module>

    chrom, stt, end, std, gID, tID = line.rstrip().split("\t")

ValueError: need more than 5 values to unpack
```

So essentially I know that somehow I am not getting more than 5 columns or values in my input data. I'm thinking the split is incorrect, but don't know what to change it to.

Here's how my input data for the script looks:

```
chrX    100629986   100630758   -   ENSG00000000003.14.IntrontENST00000373020.8.Intron

chrX    100630866   100632484   -   ENSG00000000003.14.IntrontENST00000373020.8.Intron
```

So you can see I have 5 columns of data, but the last column isn't being split properly between the gID (which is the ENSG00000000003.14.Intron) and the tID (which starts with t ... so is tENST0000373020.8.Intron).

Here's how I generated the above data using cat:

```
cat exonAnnotation.gtf intronAnnotation.gtf  | grep $'\texon\t' | sed -e 's/gene_id "//' -e 's/"; transcript_id "/\t/' -e 's/";.*$//g' | cut -f 1,4,5,7,9,10 | sort -k5,5 -k2,2n -k3,3n -s | uniq | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}{print $1, $2-1, $3, $4, $5, $6}' > minedForConstitutiveAlternativeExonIntronExtraction.bed
```

The data looks like this for the input in the cat function: The bold parts are the data i'm trying to get out.

*exonAnnotation.gtf*

```
chr1    HAVANA  exon    11869   12227   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00002234944.1"; level 2; tag "basic"; transcript_support_level "1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
```

*intronAnnotation.gtf*

```
chr1    intronAnnotation    exon    12228   12612   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5.Intron"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2.Intron"; intron_number "1"; gene_name "DDX11L1.Intron";
```

It's probably my cat function that is not working correctly, but maybe I'm just tired or really blind but I can't figure out what exactly is wrong.

Comment: No, don't leave it as is - fix your input and output to be testable so we can run a potential solution against the input and see if the output match what you want. You are doing a grep for `exon` but your input data does not contain `exon`. Fix your example or explain it. The `cat`s are doing absolutely nothing useful (nor anything harmful), get rid of them (google `UUOC`). What are you asking for help with? Converting the .gtf files to the .bed file or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I went for lunch. So i'll try to explain the best that I can, the cat function is to merge two gtf files together .. the first input you see is for my other script and essentially I want to know why my cat function is taking two of my files and not giving me six columns. So you can see that my fifth column in the top input is "ENSG00000000003.14.IntrontENST00000373020.8.Intron" when it should be "ENSG00000000003.14.Intron            tENST00000373020.8.Intron" which would give me six columns. The bottom two files are the ones i'm trying to merge and their respective data.

Comment: Your problem is in the `sed` command. Whittled down, the problem comes down to this:  `echo 'a"; transcript_id "b' | sed -e 's/"; transcript_id "/\t/'`, which gives an output of `atb`.  The command is clearly intended to replace the string with a tab separator but instead is replacing it with a literal `t`. That's why your two columns are running together with a rogue `t` in between.